# "FATAL: Cannot load configuration" after chef-client

Tags: chef-infra

I'm running the following command:

```
chef-client --local-mode -j deploy-backend.json
```

JSON file contains:

```
{
  "run-list" : [
    "deploy-dev::sysprepare",
    "deploy-dev::deploybackend",
    "deploy-dev::deploynginx"
  ]
}
```

Now the problem: chef-client command runs succesfully but gives a FATAL error at the end, after running the recipes:

```
$ sudo chef-client --local-mode -j cookbooks/deploy-backend.json 
[2017-07-13T13:19:11+02:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line, using command line options.
Starting Chef Client, version 13.2.20
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["deploy-dev::sysprepare", "deploy-dev::deploybackend", "deploy-dev::deploynginx"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - deploy-dev (0.1.0)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 29 resources
Recipe: deploy-dev::sysprepare
...
...
- reload service service[nginx]

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 11/33 resources updated in 01 minutes 32 seconds
[2017-07-13T13:20:43+02:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line, using command line options.
[2017-07-13T13:20:43+02:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line, using command line options.
[2017-07-13T13:20:43+02:00] FATAL: Cannot load configuration from cookbooks/deploy-backend.json
[2017-07-13T13:20:43+02:00] FATAL: Cannot load configuration from cookbooks/deploy-backend.json
```

I've omitted most of the output, "reload service service[nginx]" is the last resource in the runlist. I've manually verified that the recipes run correctly, but i'm getting that FATAL error at the end (this is called from a CI job, so my CI pipeline is failing because of this).

This is strange, as the execution of the recipes went ok. I'm using chef-client version 13.2.20. If i use version 12 of chef-client this executes ok. Also if i just pass the runlist:

```
chef-client --local-mode -r "deploy-dev::sysprepare,deploy-dev::deploybackend,deploy-dev::deploynginx"
```

It executes correctly. Does anybody know what's going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should use full path to your json

```
sudo chef-client --local-mode -j /opt/chef/cookbooks/deploy-backend.json
```

Comment: Worked! Do you know why is this necessary? Can you provide any link to relevant doc?

Comment: I ran into the same error. And found a solution through experiments, but there is no mention of this in the official docks

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a known bug.   https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/6427

The solo.rb file was causing the same issue. 
  As previously described, use absolute paths in the command line args.